# Is there any advantage to use Select decorator instead of select method?

Tags: ngxs

```
@Select(state => state.animals) 
animalsWithDecorator$: Observable<string[]>;
```

and

```
animalsWithMethod$ = this.store.select(state => state.animals);
```

It looks like the `select` is more type safe because if `state.animals` changes its type to `number[]` `animalsWithMethod$` also changes it but `animalsWithDecorator$` would still be `string[]`.

Comment: afaik readability when you have `@Selector()` with parameters, like, for lack of imagination `@Selector() static isLoading(loadableId): (state: any) => boolean { return createSelector([MyState], (state: any) => state.myState.loading.get(componentId));}`. Then you can simply `@Select(MyState.loading(123)) public isLoading$: Observable<boolean>;` and dont bother with `.pipe()`ing your observable to use your parameter every time you need it. (please note I am writing this code from top of my head, maybe its wrong somewhere ;) )

Answer (score -1):

Some of the advantages are [mentioned in the docs](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#store-select-function).

So, the second approach would be more useful for:

- having programmatic selectors
- selecting the state (or part of it) just once without continuously watching it
- unit testing

Comment: OP asked about the advantage of the ``Select`` decorator, so you answered the opposite question. 
Also, the second point is wrong: Neither the ``Select`` decorator nor ``store.select`` select only once. That's what you would use ``store.selectSnapshot`` or ``store.selectOnce`` for.